# R: Numbering rows consecutively

Tags: r

How can I number rows in a sorted data frame consecutively, starting at 1 whenever a new id begins?

What I have:

```
id | value
a | 2
a | 6
a | 1
a | 10
a | 12
b | 5
b | 2
b | 3
...
```

What  I want:

```
id | value | t
a | 2 | 1
a | 6 | 2
a | 1 | 3
a | 10 | 4
a | 12 | 5
b | 5 | 1
b | 2 | 2
b | 3 | 3
...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [input sequential numbers without specific end in a data frame's column in r](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23007982/input-sequential-numbers-without-specific-end-in-a-data-frames-column-in-r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DF <- read.table(text="id | value
a | 2
a | 6
a | 1
a | 10
a | 12
b | 5
b | 2
b | 3", sep="|", header=TRUE)

DF$t <- sequence(rle(as.character(DF$id))$lengths)
#   id value t
# 1 a      2 1
# 2 a      6 2
# 3 a      1 3
# 4 a     10 4
# 5 a     12 5
# 6 b      5 1
# 7 b      2 2
# 8 b      3 3
```

Comment: `data.table`, `dplyr`, `tapply` and `ave` alternatives [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288462/replace-loop-with-an-pply-alternative/22288615#22288615).

Comment: @Henrik `sequence` and `rle` should be very efficient. So, I'm not sure when you'd use one of these alternatives.

Comment: @Roland, Thanks for your comment. Sorry if I phrased it in a way that may have suggested that your alternative was slow(er). That was not my intention. I referred (sloppily) only to the comparison among alternatives _within_ the answer I pointed to. I have edited my comment.

Comment: @Henrik That's because you benchmark `as.character` with that. If you make sure that the column is not a factor and don't need `as.character` the timings are different. `data.table` will be faster though.

Comment: @Henrik It does on my system. It takes only one third of the time needed with `ave`.

Comment: It's nice to see all of these alternatives, but how large of a dataset do we have to have to get to get out of millisecond timings?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this -

```
gr_index    <- as.numeric(table(df$id))
df$gr_index <- unlist(lapply(gr_index, seq_len))
```

I have found this faster the ddply or split commands, especially on large data sets.